# How to change Leaflet Map panes layering order (z-index)?

Tags: leaflet, z-index

Leaflet maintains that the Map panes elements contain all layers added to the map. The difference between many of the Map panes is strictly the z-index order of layering.

I would like to use a combination of lvector.CartoDB layers, which are essentially `overlayPane` layers, with TileLayer, such as GeoIQ Acetate-bg and labels.

This is the ordering of the elements as they are added the map:

```js
tileLayer1 = new L.TileLayer();
map.add(tileLayer1);  // add first layer to map

cartoDBLayer1 = new lvector.CartoDB();
cartoDBLayer.setMap(map); // add second layer to map

tileLayer2 = new L.TileLayer();
map.add(tileLayer2);  // add third layer to map
```

What returns is a map with layers in this order:

```
tileLayer1,tileLayer2,cartoDBLayer1
```

`tileLayer1` and `tileLayer2` are situated in the `HTMLElement: TilePane` and `cartoDBLayer1` is in `HTMLElement: overlayPane`.

Is there any way to force `cartoDBLayer1` to render in the TilePane, such that it falls in order of the z-index that it is added to the map in...

i.e.

```js
z-index[0]:tileLayer1
z-index[1]:cartoDBLayer1
z-index[2]:tileLayer2
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update Sept 2014**

Leaflet now supports setting the [zIndex](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-setzindex). Thanks to @knutole in the comments for letting me know.

**Old Answer**

Have you seen this issue created one the LeafLet github repo:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/167

try to use

```
 addLayer(layer,true);
```

to add a tile layer to the bottom. I'm afraid that's all there is and this second optional argument is not even documented.

Comment: +1 for mentioning an undocumented feature here, thus documenting it. :)

Comment: There is now a [`layer.setZIndex(zIndex)`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-setzindex) function available.

Comment: Thanks - `layer.setZIndex(99)` doesn't seem to work for me with vector symbology (line and polygon features), but using `layer.bringToFront()` did the trick.

Comment: The equivalent call for `L.Marker` is [`layer.setZIndexOffset(...)`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker-method)

Comment: @diachedelic unfortunately `CircleMarker` aren't `Marker`, they're `Path`... I have a `CircleMarker` and I can't make it display above a permanent `Tooltip`