# Make a leaflet TileLayer appear above a GeoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to add a layer of place labels **above** a GeoJSON layer, so that these labels remain visible. However when I add the layer per the code below, the tileLayer remains below the GeoJSON layer.

```
    var CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 19,
        zIndex: 3
    });
    CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels.addTo(map);
```

Adding a few more things that **don't work** for the future reader:

1. According to [this leaflet PR](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2266) you could add a `pane: 'overlayPane'` option upon layer creation.
2. The hack appearing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18967523/4047679) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939607/overlay-below-tiles-in-leaflet-js) **only works** if the tileLayer you're adding is of tileJSON format

   ```
   var topPane = map._createPane('leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);  
   var topLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('lxbarth.map-vtt23b1i').addTo(map);  
   topPane.appendChild(topLayer.getContainer());  
   topLayer.setZIndex(9);
   ```

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20331/how-to-change-leaflet-map-panes-layering-order-z-index See this question. You have to alter the z-index.

Comment: Nice try, but z-index only alters draw order *within* a pane, it won't make the tilelayer pane render above the overlay pane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barrett's answer set me down the right path, but I ended up in such a number of rabbit holes that I decided that posting my resulting code and explanation of some of my discoveries in the hopes this might help the community.

The resulting code that worked is as below.

```
var CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels = {
    "tilejson": "2.0.1",
    "tiles":['http://c.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'], 
    "attribution": '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; 
         <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
    "maxzoom": 19,
    "minzoom": 13       
};

var topPane = map._createPane('leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);
var topLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer(CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels).addTo(map);
topPane.appendChild(topLayer.getContainer());
topLayer.setZIndex(9);
```

The second half of that code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19958325/4047679). I had to modify it because the `L.mapbox.tileLayer` doesn't work the same way as `L.tileLayer`, it requires a `tileJSON` as input ([spec](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec/)), which is what that first section of code defines.

You'll notice a difference from the parameters provided in tileLayer code examples like the handy [Leaflet Providers](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/): the absence of the subdomain `{s}` in the url. This is because, well, [this](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec/issues/13). Fortunately, cartoDB explicitly lists those subdomains (`abcd`) so I picked `c` and added that to the start of the tile URLs and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

[Panes](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panes) might help your cause. The idea being you can control what layers draw in what panes and then control the pane order. [Here is the original GIT discusson on it.](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1742)

There is also a similar [SO question regarding overlay layers and tile layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939607/overlay-below-tiles-in-leaflet-js) and how they are implemented on custom panes.